# mpz_t to digit array c++

Tags: c++, gmp

i need to convert a mpz_t to a int array including the digits.
e.g.

```
mpz_t t1; mpz_set_si(t1,12345); int digits[];
mpz_t2digits(t1,digits); //That function I need
//digits should now be {1,2,3,4,5}
```

I know there is a function named,

```
mpz_export (void *rop, size_t *countp, int order, size_t size, int endian, size_t nails, const mpz_t op)
```

but that doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

In two steps. First convert the number to an array of characters where each character represents a digit. Use `mpz_get_str (char *str, int base, const mpz_t op)`. Then convert each character (a digit) in that array to an integer. One way is by subtracting 48 (the ASCII code for '0') from each character if you don't mind a little hack.

By the way, `mpz_set_si` is for signed integers. How are you going to represent negative numbers in your resulting `digits[]`? Maybe `mpz_set_ui` (for unsigned int) might be more appropriate.

Comment: I presume the most time consuming part is the base conversion from binary to decimal which is something that cannot be avoided here. The additional conversion of characters to integers is a simple `O(n)` operation. If performance is something you worry about, then maybe you can update the question with some more context as to what this function `mpz_t2digits` would be used for, and the size of the input numbers?